# Why am I encountering a 'Column requires a valid DataType' error when processing dimensions in Visual Studio OLAP cube?

Tags: visual-studio

**Error related to DataType when processing dimensions in Visual Studio OLAP cube.**

Hello,
I'm currently working on **creating an OLAP cube** in **Visual Studio**, and I'm facing an issue when **processing dimensions**. The error I'm encountering is related to **DataType**, but I believe that my data types are set correctly.

**Here's the specific error message I'm receiving:**

1. Internal error: The operation terminated unsuccessfully.
2. Errors in the high-level relational engine. The following exception occurred while an operation was being performed on a data source view: Column requires a valid DataType..
3. Errors in the high-level relational engine. The following exception occurred while an operation was being performed on a data source view
4. Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while the dimension, with the ID of 'Customer', Name of 'Customer' was being processed.
5. Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while the 'Customer Key' attribute of the 'Customer' dimension from the 'OLAP' database was being processed.
6. Server: The current operation was cancelled because another operation in the transaction failed.

**Screenshot of the error in Visual Studio:**

[image]

**Dimension properties in Visual Studio:**

[image]

**Design of the table in SSMS:**
[image]

I would **appreciate any insights or suggestions** on how to resolve this issue and successfully process the dimensions in my OLAP cube.

**What I have tried?**

1. I have thoroughly checked the data types of all attributes in each dimension, and they seem to be correct according to the data source.
2. I have recreated project many times, same error in every project.
3. I have tried to explore the data in Visual Studio to verify that the data source has a connection to DW and the connection is without problem.
4. I have tried to check the forum, to google the error. Without any sucessfull hint what could cause the problem.
5. I have checked the data in SSMS, there are not IDs in wrong format, Null value or duplicated IDs.
6. I have tried to process the dimension also with other attributes, it gave me the same error.